# Bootstrap button group justified not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'interface:data' user_id 24 %}"> 24h </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'interface:data' user_id 12 %}"> 12h </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'interface:data' user_id 4 %}"> 4h </a>
</div>
```

I get the following result: [image]

Why I don't get this result?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have indicated, `.btn-group-justified` was depreciated in Bootstrap 4.  In the Migration documentation we are provided an alternative:

> Removed **.btn-group-justified**. As a replacement you can use `<div class="**btn-group d-flex**" role="group"></div>` as a wrapper around
>   elements with **.w-100**.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#button-group

Utilizing this new setup your code would look like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group">
  <a class="btn btn-success w-100" > 24h </a>
  <a class="btn btn-success w-100" > 12h </a>
  <a class="btn btn-success w-100" > 4h </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `.btn-group-justified` class has been removed from Bootstrap 4 ([source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17631))

You can accomplish the same thing with just a little bit of CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a class="btn btn-success" > 24h </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" > 12h </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" > 4h </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
   width:100%;
}
div {
   width:100%;
}
```